# Smarty Undefined Index Variable

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I am newbie to smarty and trying to output some results in my tpl file fetching from php. In my `account.php` file I have put Below code

```
<?php
  include SMARTYLOADER;
  $ad2 = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM ip_ptc");
  $smarty->assign("ad2", $ad2);
  $smarty->display("account.tpl");
  $db->close();
  exit();
 ?>
```

and in my `account.tpl` file i have written below code to fetch the result

```
{$ad2.country}
```

but it is showing an undefined index variable `ad2` what's wrong i am doing

Comment: it seems incomplete, you've not even instantiated smarty variable... can you post more

Comment: hi can you help how can i instantiated smarty variable?

Comment: is this the exact code you're trying to execute? can you post your folder structure? basically you need to put `$smarty = new Smarty()` right before assign, though this might not work unless you give some insight on how you're getting things done on your end

Comment: There is documentation available on how to install/setup Smarty: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl